# What is the difference between 款式 and 格式

Tags: difference

I know both of them mean "style", but don't know the difference between the two words.

Can somebody tell me the difference? I would appreciate it

Comment: Actually, 格式 is more like 'format' (like e.g. "file format", etc.), and 款式 is like general style (trend), like e.g. as in "latest Paris style".

Comment: in case a given dictionary (which ?) only has "style" for both, some users would suggest consulting additional online dictionaries e.g. iciba:格式 form; format; pattern; layout 款式:model; style; design; fashion; pattern (also there find example sentences and compounds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way out of your conundrum is to realize your original assumption `I know both of them mean "style"` is the source of confusion.

Words can become flexible and have more than one meaning, or "senses of the word". However, usually when asking about the meaning of a word, we are talking about the primary, or most common usage of a word.

In this case, even if both 款式 and 格式 can sometimes be used as "style", only one of them can be considered "style" as its primary use, primary meaning.

### 款式

Out of the choices, only this would have a primary meaning of "style"

[CDICT search for 款式](http://cdict.net/?q=%E6%AC%BE%E5%BC%8F) translates this as:

- pattern
- style
- design

### 格式

[CDICT search for 格式](http://cdict.net/?q=%E6%A0%BC%E5%BC%8F) translates this as:

- form
- specification
- format

On a more technical note, [Yellowbridge etymology on the word 格](http://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E6%A0%BC) shows

- 木 [mù] tree; wood, lumber; wooden
- 各 [gè] each, individually, every, all

Perhaps one way think of what this word means, is that, at least in ancient times when this word was developed, wood was commonly thought of as a practical material for making, reshaping all kinds of different "forms" or "things"

In Taoism, Traditional Chinese Medicine, Feng Shui, within their five elements, 木 or "wood element" is associated with creation/creating.

### Conclusion

So, as long as you can let go of the idea that both "mean" style, then you can see that the difference in these terms is:

- 款式's primary use/meaning/sense is "style"
- 格式's primary use/meaning/sense is "form"

Unless you are not sure what the difference between the words "style" and "form", that would be new question then.